# Replace element from list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {3, 1}, {5, 4}, {7, 8}, {8, 9},   {15, 0}, {6, 7}, {9, 7}, {4, 3}, {6, 3}};
list1 = {{a, b}, {d, e}, {t, r}};
```

I want to replace some elements of list by list1.

Final Result would be look like

```
finallist = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {3, 1},{a, b}, {d, e},{8, 9},{15, 0}, {6, 7}, {9, 7}, {4, 3}, {6, 3}};
```

Please help me, if possible

Comment: You could use something like `Module[{r = list}, r[[6 ;; 7]] = list1[[1 ;; 2]]; r]`

Comment: Thank you but if your list is too big then how could I know position of elements. I do not like to count manually. Please Carl help me, I am new in Mathematica

Comment: but what is the criterion of the replacement? in your list you could use list /. {{5, 4} -> list1[[1]], {7, 8} -> list1[[2]]}, but pls note that this would replace all the {5,4} and {7,8} elements of your list (even if in your example there is just one occurrence of each)

Comment: Also, can you please edit your question explicitly specifying what you need (independence from element position etc.)?

Comment: Fraccalo , suppose you have a list with 1000 elements then, how could you find any elements without counting manually?

Comment: Note, that you can edit your original question to make it more precise. Also check out the `Position` function.

Comment: @RonySaha you should really formalise what your problem is, and then edit the main question. At the moment, it's not clear whether you want to replace two specific items in the list, if you want to find their positions, if there is a pattern that you want to replace, a combination of the above or other. Please try to explain carefully what you want to achieve in the post above (use edit button) and we are happy to help you as possible

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UpdatePartsOfAMatrix.html Refer to the info in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Rony, "how could you find any elements without counting manually".
Is this what you are looking for?

```
Position[list, {5, 4}]
```